# Ruby Trees with full path on leaves

Tags: ruby, algorithm, tree

I have an array of paths:

```
    paths = ["home", "usr/lib/folder1/", "usr/lib/folder2/"]
```

I tried to make a tree with full path on the ends (leaves):

```
    {"home" => "home", "usr" => {"lib" => {"folder1" => "usr/lib/folder1/", "folder2" => "usr/lib/folder2/"}}}
```

This is my code:

```
  paths.each do |path|
    current = tree
    path.split('/').inject('') do |_sub_path, dir|
      sub_path = File.join(dir)
      current[sub_path] ||= {path => {}}
      current = current[sub_path]
      sub_path
    end
 end
```

Can you show me the right way for my question?
This is my first question on SO. Sorry if my English bad.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to create a Trie like data structure. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

This will do it but its not tested nor is it very Rubyish...

```
paths = ["home", "usr/lib/folder1/", "usr/lib/folder2/"]

ans =
  paths.reduce({}){
  |acc, e|
  last = e.split('/').last
  e.split('/').reduce(acc){
    |acc, n|
    acc[n] = {} if acc[n].nil?
    acc[n] = e if n == last
    acc[n]
  }
  acc
}

p ans
```

What's your strategy for adding more paths?I.E. If you have to add another path like "home/user/data" and "/home/user/docs" or "usr/lib/folder1/data" and "usr/lib/folder2/data", what's your strategy?

Comment: @Cary: It really doesn't matter if I don't know(and I don't account for) situations which run down the same branch... What do you you do with the string at the end of the branch if you extend the branch?

Comment: I was merely confirming that your code worked for the example as you said you had not tested it. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "...run down the same branch", but if `"usr/lib/folder2/cat/"` is added to `paths` an exception is raised by the line `acc[n] = {} if acc[n].nil?`: `IndexError (string not matched)`. At that point `acc #=> 'usr/lib/folder2/'` and `n => 'cat'`.

Comment: @Cary I was never a big fan of building a complex data structure with straight method calls. If I had a choice... I'd solve this by creating a proper module for the data structure.

Answer (score 0):

This could be solved recursively.

```
def recurse(arr, arr_build = [])
  return arr_build.join('/') if arr == [[]]
  arr.group_by { |a| a.first }.
      transform_values { |v| recurse(v.map { |a| a.drop(1) },
        arr_build + [v.first.first]) }
end
```

```
recurse(paths.map { |s| s.split('/') })
  #=> {"home"=>"home",
  #    "usr"=>{"lib"=>{"folder1"=>"usr/lib/folder1",
  #                    "folder2"=>"usr/lib/folder2"}}}
```

See [Enumerable#group_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) and [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values).

Note that when

```
arr = paths.map { |s| s.split('/') }
  #=> [["home"], ["usr", "lib", "folder1"], ["usr", "lib", "folder2"]]
```

we find that

```
arr.group_by { |a| a.first }
  #=> {"home"=>[["home"]],
  #    "usr"=>[["usr", "lib", "folder1"], ["usr", "lib", "folder2"]]}
```